# How to solve Illegal offset type on the laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use this : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I use laravel 5.3

My laravel eloquent is like this :

```
$data = Employee::select('id', DB::raw('sum(salary+bonus) AS total'), 'name')->find($id);
dd($data);
```

So, I want sum 2 field in one record

When executed, there exist error like this :

> 1/1 ErrorException in Builder.php line 353: Illegal offset type

How can I solve it?

Comment: I would go to `Builder.php` line 353 and see what its trying to set. Then you might be able to work back to see whats causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
    $data = Employee::select('id', DB::raw('sum(salary + bonus) as total'), 'name')->find();

    Or you can try this way

    $data = Employee::select('id', 'name', sum(DB::raw('salary + bonus')))->find($id);
dd($data);
```